# tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized for .get_users_tweets()

Tags: python, tweepy

I keep getting this error:

> tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

and I am not even trying to post anything, just want to get the tweets of one account.
I have regenerated and updated my `api_key`, `api_secret` and `bearer token` three times already.

```
import requests
import tweepy
import configparser

from tweepy import Client, OAuthHandler

config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)
config.read('config.txt')

api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_secret = config['twitter']['api_secret']

access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_secret = config['twitter']['access_secret']

bearer_token = config['twitter']['bearer_token']
auth: OAuthHandler = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
#auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

username = "ZssBecker"
userid_bkr = '1243470638477697024'
twclient = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token, consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_secret, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#twclient: Client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token, consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_secret, access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=access_secret, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

twclient.get_users_tweets(id=userid_bkr)
```

I tried a bunch of suggestions from other threads and updating my tokens.
Want a response of the accounts tweets.

Edit: Solved: the issue was that I used quotation marks in my config file for my keys.

Comment: Could this be related to the recent API changes on Twitter's end? (genuine question; the status there keeps changing, sometimes in unannounced/undocumented ways)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving tweets is now a PAID function of the Twitter/X API.
The free access only includes "manage tweets" (post/delete) and "user lookups" (details about users, follower count, bio, etc), but **it does NOT include "tweets lookups".**

As of today, the "tweets lookup" function is accessible through the Basic plan, at 100$/month.